# Mysterious IndexError - very basic issue (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, numpy

I'm having a problem with a bit of code, I feel like I must be missing something fundamental here. A simple example that gives the same error as I am having is as follows:

```
from numpy import array,zeros
x = array([1,2,3])
f = zeros(len(x))

for i in x:
    f[i] = x[i] + 1
```

And the traceback reads as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\<ipython-input-5-6b6b88f30156> in <module>()
      1 for i in x:
----> 2     f[i] = x[i] + 1
      3 

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

This has been puzzling me for far too long, but I just can't seem to see what the problem is here? Could someone lend a hand?

Comment: I'm impressed you didn't get an error on `array[(1, 2, 3)]` or the lack of `zeros` being imported... - are you copying/pasting code, or typing it in?

Comment: Typing it in, it was done correctly in the console, sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for i in x:
    f[i] = x[i] + 1
```

`i` takes the values 1, 2 and then 3. `x[i]` is not what you think it is. `i` already contains the content of a cell of the array `x`. Since the indexes of the array start from 0, you do an `IndexError` when trying to get the element of index 3 (which would be the 4th element).

You probably wanted something such as:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    f[i] = x[i] + 1
```

That could also be written:

```
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    f[i] = v + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `for i in some_list`, `i` refers to elements of that list, rather than their indexes. For example:

```
In [1]: for i in [3, 2, 1]:
   ...:     print i
   ...:     
3
2
1
```

However, you then use `i` as an index.

You iterate with `i` over `x`, and thus `i` takes values of `1`,  `2` and `3`. But `3` is a too big index for an array of length 3. The last index is `2`, as in Python indexes start with 0.

Comment: I think I see, so even though Python indexes start with `0` the `for` loop starts at `i=1`? In that case, adding an extra element to `f` should fix my problem, but that doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution?

Comment: @user3008862 It starts with `i=1` because `1` is the 0-th element of the array. I expanded the answer a bit to make it clearer.